# Let $F=\Bbb Z_2$ and let $f(x)=x^3+x+1 \in F[x]$. Express each member of $F(a)$ in terms of $a$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $F=\Bbb Z_2$ and let $f(x)=x^3+x+1 \in F[x]$. Suppose $a$ is a zero of $f(x)$ in some extension of $F$. How many elements does $F(a)$ have? Express each member of $F(a)$ in terms of $a$.

As $\deg(f(x)) =3$ and for any $x \in F$ we have that $f(x) \ne 0$. Thus $f$ is irreducible and we can conclude that $F(a) \cong F[x]/\langle f(x) \rangle$.

Since $F[x]/\langle f(x) \rangle=\Bbb Z_2[x]/\langle f(x)\rangle$ has $2^3=8$ elements we know that $F(a)$ has $8$ elements.

How can I figure out what the elements of $F(a)$ are in terms of $a$?

Comment: That last question is a bit artificial, since there are a lot of ways to express the elements of $F$ in terms of $a.$ But the usual way is as $p(a)$ for $p(x)\in F[x]$ and $\deg p<3.$ But it could be $p(a+1)$ for $\deg p(x)<3.$ Even $p(a^2)$ works.

Answer (score 1):

As for any cubic field, you can express them via
$$
c_0+c_1a+c_2a^2, \ c_i\in F.
$$

Comment: Additional comments: All these are obviously in $F(a)$, and if two of them were equal, the difference of the polynomials which form them would need to be a factor of $f$. If we needed to build the multiplication table for these representations, we just multiply them out then use $a^3 = -(a+1) = a+1$.